# Passing data with inheritance?

Tags: ruby, inheritance

I have several classes that inherit from a single class. Each child class creates some data structures then the parent class performs operations on that data.

**Question:** How do I get the parent class to use that data regardless of whether the object is instantiated or not.

```
class A
  def self.static_test
    puts @myvar + "_static"
  end
  def instantiated_test
    puts @myvar + "_instantiated"
  end
end
class B<A
  @myvar = "this works B"
end
class C<A
  @myvar = "this works C"
end

B.static_test
B.new.instantiated_test
C.static_test
C.new.instantiated_test
B.static_test
B.new.instantiated_test
```

I would need the above code to print:

```
this works B_static
this works B_instantiated
this works C_static
this works C_instantiated
this works B_static
this works B_instantiated
```

I am using Ruby 1.8.7.

**Edit:** It looks like my original question was a bit confusing. I need both static and instantiated methods to use the same data. The methods won't be doing the same thing though. I updated the sample code to reflect this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class A
  class << self
    attr_reader :myvar
  end
  # Alternatively:
  # def self.myvar; @myvar; end

  def self.static_test
    puts myvar
  end
  def instantiated_test
    puts self.class.myvar
  end
end
class B<A
  @myvar = "this works B"
end
class C<A
  @myvar = "this works C"
end

B.static_test
#=> this works B
B.new.instantiated_test
#=> this works B
C.static_test
#=>this works C
C.new.instantiated_test
#=>this works C
B.static_test
#=> this works B
B.new.instantiated_test
#=> this works B
```

Comment: Oh anonymous drive-by downvoter, why, why?! :p Seriously, if you think this answer is misleading or harmful, it would be very helpful to indicate why.

Comment: It would be nice if the SE interface forced downvoters to leave a comment.

Comment: I still think your answer is the correct one. Mladen's answer assumes that both the instantiated and static methods are identical. I edited the question to state that they are not.

Comment: Agreed, I upvoted this answer too, as more instructive. One thing OP should remember is that instance variables always belong to exactly one.. er.. instance. In his code, `static_test` and `instantiated_test` methods belong to different instances (first to class `A` itself - classes in Ruby are objects too, remember - second to each of its instances). Therefore, `@myvar` variables are also in different objects and only way to access them from the outside is through methods.

Answer (score 3):

```
def instantiated_test
  self.class.static_test
end
```

BTW, if you are sure that inherited classes will have a certain structure, extract it to parent class. If you are not sure, don't use it at all from parent class. Parent's implementation should not depend on child's implementation.

Comment: Nice, better (DRYer) code than mine. I'll +1 you when I get more votes later.

Answer (score 0):

```
class A
  def self.static_test
    puts @myvar
  end
  def instantiated_test
    puts @myvar
  end
end
class B<A
  @myvar = "this works B"
  @@myvar = @myvar
  def initialize
    @myvar = @@myvar
  end
end
class C<A
  @myvar = "this works C"
  @@myvar = @myvar
  def initialize
    @myvar = @@myvar
  end
end
```

But this is ugly and requires duplication.